# winform2 using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

```
frmCustomerDetails cd;
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {               
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        this.Hide();
        if (cd == null || cd.IsDisposed)
        {
            cd = new frmCustomerDetails();
            cd.MdiParent = new frmDairyManagementSystem();
            cd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            cd.Show();
        }
        else
            cd.Activate();
        cd.txtCustomerID.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cd.dateTimePicker1.Text=dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtCustomerName.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cd.grpGender.Text=dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtAddress.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtPhone.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtEmail.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtMobileNo.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtNotes.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        cd.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnDelete.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        cd.txtCustomerName.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

In my main form I have opened a child form using Mdi.

The child form's name is CustomerDetails. In that form if I want to Update or Delete already existing Customer, I have added a button in front of CustomerName. On click of that button a new form is opened, named CustomerRecord. In that form I have used DataGridView and I have written code to retrieve the data from database to it.

Now I want that if dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick is clicked, I want to get the selected row on CustomerDetails form.

The above code is not working.

One more issue is occuring that below dateTimePicker, grpGender is also not working.

This is my first project that I am doing as a project that I have to submit it to college.

It is not taking to my main form.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not going to work:

```
cd.MdiParent = new frmDairyManagementSystem();
```

The MDI parent must be the top-level form.  And then within that, you instantiate children and add them to the mdi collection.

If `frmDairyManagementSystem` is the parent, it must be alive and visible.